# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Do fricatives turn into affricates after nasal consonants, and why?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6574/do-fricatives-turn-into-affricates-after-nasal-consonants-and-why)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Most tones contrasting by pitch and not just contour?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6522/most-tones-contrasting-by-pitch-and-not-just-contour)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [In which of these sentences is “and” used for coordination?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6482/in-which-of-these-sentences-is-and-used-for-coordination)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Dependency Grammar constraints](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6536/dependency-grammar-constraints)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Which part of speech are 's' and 'r' in Wordnet?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6508/which-part-of-speech-are-s-and-r-in-wordnet)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the word-order categories "Subject", "verb", "object" called?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6469/what-are-the-word-order-categories-subject-verb-object-called)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the extension and intension of "I'm writing an exam right now."](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6465/what-is-the-extension-and-intension-of-im-writing-an-exam-right-now)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Cohesion within a sentence?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/cohesion-within-a-sentence)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Are personal pronouns in English different lexemes or just inflected forms of the same one?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/are-personal-pronouns-in-english-different-lexemes-or-just-inflected-forms-of-th)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is the case described below hypothetical or does it occur in natural languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/is-the-case-described-below-hypothetical-or-does-it-occur-in-natural-languages)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Comment: What? @NetworkUser